# Copy Autocad drawings in Office 2013

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, autocad

I'm trying to copy and paste an Autocad 2016 drawing into MS Publisher 2013. When I paste the drawing into Publisher (or Word too) it is rendered in a very low quality. While with Publisher 2007 i don't have tris problem, I can't get the same result with the newer version.
Anyone is aware of this issue and knows how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you try to export the drawing from AutoCAD to CGM or WGF?

Comment: No but I can't understand why with Office 2007 I had no problem with direct Copy/paste from Autocad and now with Office 2013 I have this issue.

Comment: Maybe is related to OLE objects and way office handle them. And IMHO will be better to use some common intermediate format because on the OS where you do not have AutoCAD installed you can get probably only lowlevel preview image in the document. BTW above i mean WMF, not WGF.